# How to click on upper left menus even if a modal dialog is opened?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, modal

I want to open modal dialog box in inside the `aura:component`. I followed [this](https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/04/15/modal-box-lightning-component-salesforce) tutorial to achieve this. The dialog box is opening fine. But, when the dialog box is opened, I cannot click on any of the upper left menu items, I mean, these menus:
[image]

I fine with being not able to click anything inside the `aura:component`. But, is there any way to open the dialog box in such a way that I can click the menu items?

**UPDATE:**
Screenshot of the page:
[image]

Comment: You really shouldn't want this. The definition of a modal is that it takes precendence over everything else. It should be dealt with first, before you can do something else. This is universal, if your modal behaves differently, your users will be confused. If your modal requires that you can access other UI elements as well, you should not be using a modal.

Comment: @SanderdeJong I understand that. I dont want to access other ui elements. I want to access only the menu items mentioned in the question. I thought as it is not part of the app, it should be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below code lines-

```html
<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
```

Comment: still not working.

Comment: It should. Because the lines mentioned above makes modal as modeless. Means you can do any opration behind the popup. Can you post updated screenshot, which will be easy to debug

Comment: I have added the screenshot to the question.